# Компонент Android Studio для отображения текста и изображений

Tags: android

Есть массив строк с элементами, содержащими просто текст и с элементами, содержащими http-ссылки на изображения. 
Какой компонент Android Studio лучше использовать, чтобы в цикле от первого до последнего элемента массива поочередно добавлять на него элементы массива с текстом и подгружать сами изображения?
Если нет решения с одним компонентом, то, вероятно, придется динамически программно добавлять на активность TextView и ImageView при каждой смене содержимого в этом случае?

Comment: Может Вам нужен adapter и listView?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен вам нужно вывести список состоящий из таких элементов?

Comment: Kirill Stoianov, нет, нужно отобразить текст и, если встречаются элементы со ссылками на изображения, подгрузить эти изображения.

Comment: как вариант выводите все на webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте ListView/RecyclerView для которого создайте CustomAdapter. В CustomAadapter для каждой записи подгружайте xml своего View (TextView + ImageView). Для подгрузки изображений советую использовать Picasso. 
Подключение Picasso в gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
```

Пример Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http адрес картинки").into(imageView);
```